# Is it okay to have same name of parameter and variable in function call in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, named-parameters

i have query that is it fine to use to use named parameter which having name parameter and the variable name same in a function call

for example

```
fun fun1( to:string ){
//body}

fun fun2( ){
to = "xyz"
fun1( to = to)
}
```

calling fun1 which have a parameter name "to" and passing variable "to" is it okay to do so . In either of case can someone also explain how the compiler will resolve this

Comment: "is it okay to do so" What do you mean by "okay"?

Comment: Outside of formatting and naming mistakes, what you're asking is valid Kotlin and behaves where the value of `to` in `fun2` gets `"xyz"`.  I assume you're coming from a C background or a language that lets you do assignment in a function argument.  You can't do assignment in a function argument in Kotlin (try it) so there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin, property or variable assignment can only happen if the variable/property name and `=` are at the beginning of a line of code (or the first code in the scope `{ }` of a lambda or defined function), not in the middle of an expression or list of function arguments.

Since the compiler sees `to =` inside the argument list of a function call, it resolves it as a named argument rather than a variable assignment, so the `to` of `to =` is interpreted as a function parameter name.